# Problems with angularjs services tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, jasmine, karma-runner

Someone can help me with this issue, I wrote following service in angularjs:

```
angular
.module('myapp')
.factory('emailsService', [
    '$http',
    'serviceConfig',
    function($http, serviceConfig){

        function sendEmail(data){
            var options = {
                method: 'POST',
                data: $.param(data),
                url: serviceConfig.base + 'api/email',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            };

            return $http(options)

        }

        return {
            sendEmail: sendEmail
        }
    }]);
```

To service above I wrote test below:

```
'use strict';

describe('EmailsServiceTest', function() {
var emailsService;
var $httpBackend;
var fakeEmail = {
        email_filters: [],
        filters_on: true,
        content: "blabalalba",
        subject: "blabalalba",
        brokers: [],
        type: [],
        to: []
    };

//Load module, before anything
beforeEach(module('myapp'));

//Some stuffs that we'll need
beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, _emailsService_){
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    emailsService = _emailsService_;

}));

it('Testing method return', function(){
    $httpBackend.when('POST',  'http://localhost:8000/insure/api/email', fakeEmail).respond(200, {});

    emailsService.sendEmail(fakeEmail)
        .then(function(response){
            expect(response).not.toBe(undefined);
        }, function () {

        });
})

});
```

Until here it's ok, but when I run the test, the karma-cli output show following error:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) EmailsServiceTest Testing method return FAILED
    Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: emailsServiceProvider <- emailsService
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.7/$injector/unpr?p0=emailsServiceProvider%20%3C-%20emailsService (line 3992)
    /home/felipe/Development/**/assets/js/angular/angular.js:3992:86
    getService@/home/felipe/Development/**/assets/js/angular/angular.js:4139:46
    /home/felipe/Development/**/assets/js/angular/angular.js:3997:48
    getService@/home/felipe/Development/**/assets/js/angular/angular.js:4139:46
    invoke@/home/felipe/Development/**/assets/js/angular/angular.js:4171:23
    workFn@/home/felipe/Development/**/assets/js/angular/angular-mocks.js:2350:26
    undefined
    TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$httpBackend.when') in /home/felipe/Development/**/tests/emailsService_test.js (line 36)
    /home/felipe/Development/**/tests/emailsService_test.js:36:21
```

Someone can help me with question, I tried follow [this](https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/12/unit-testing-services-in-angularjs-for-fun-and-for-profit/) tutorial and [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services#creating-services) but I had no positive result.

**UPDATE**

Aparently the problem was that I forgot of load the module containing the service

I added the piece of code below and solved my issue.

```
beforeEach(module('myapp.email'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide your Karma configuration file ? I probably suspect that you are missing to add the file names in the file array of Karma configuration file.

Note: Check the files option in the below link. 
http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

Comment: Hello guy, I reviewed my karm.cong.js and was ok, I updated my question with the solution that solved my problem, but thanks for your help.